# How do I use a macro to redefine a function in release mode?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros

Using C++, I need a macro that will replace a function to do nothing if it is running in release mode. So, in debug mode the function will be executed, but in release mode it will not.

Something like this:

```
static void foo(int,int)

#ifdef NDEBUG
#define foo(x,y)
#endif
```

...and the function body is defined in a separate .cpp file and is part of a class, which is why I think this isn't working?

actual code..

header

```
static void ValidateInput(const SeriesID *CurrentSeries, const AEnum_TT_TICK_ROUND& roundType = TT_TICK_ROUND_NONE);
```

.cpp

```
void TTBaseTick::ValidateInput(const SeriesID *CurrentSeries, const AEnum_TT_TICK_ROUND& roundType)
{
#ifndef _DEBUG
if (!CurrentSeries)
{
  throw TTTick::Ex(TTTick::SeriesNull);
}
else if (CurrentSeries->precision <= 0)
{
    throw TTTick::Ex(TTTick::PrecisionInvalid);
}
else if(!roundType.IsValidValue(roundType))
{
    throw TTTick::Ex(TTTick::InvalidParam);
}
#endif
}
```

Comment: Why can't you do that to the function definition itself in the .cpp file?

Comment: Is foo a static member function of a class declared somewhere else?

Comment: Mysticial -I get a no object file generated error
H3nr1x - No, it is only declared in this class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static void foo(int,int); // declaration



// Definition in your cpp file.
void foo( int x, int y )
{
#ifndef NDEBUG
    // Code for debug mode
#endif
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because i get an error that no object file was generated

Comment: @user1513555 Working fine for me. It could be some other issue. Can you post the code where you used it?

Comment: posted in original post, i think probably because the data types aren't actually integers?

Comment: @Bullsfan127 Is `AEnum_TT_TICK_ROUND` an enum?

Comment: Yes, it's a compile time agile enum

Comment: @Bullsfan127 I've created code that compiles fine in codepad from your given code (making some differences like stubbing/commenting out some of the dependencies that are not given). Check this code http://codepad.org/UjbJjzVh. This might help finding the real issue.

Comment: @Bullsfan127 "compile time agile enum" looks like a new term to me. Btw, Is your the code working when you remove the #ifndef part ?

Comment: Yea, im not really familiar with it either, looks like something we just defined. But i figured out how to make this work, i just #ifdef the function headers, and body to only be defined in debug mode and then used a #define validateinput(x,y) to replace any calls i made to it..not sure why the other solution was not working though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Though the compiler may omit the call to `foo` function, since this function would do nothing in Release mode. It is not good approach.

Comment: @Ajay I didn't get you properly. What's wrong if the compiler omit the call during release build? The function does nothing anyway in release mode. The call cannot be omitted in case of debug build rt?

Comment: 1. In Release build, the compiler will optimize the function, and the call itself - which means No-OP. This function wouldn't exist!
2. It's not the point if the function does something or not. If NOT optimized away, it incurs call stack usage, which is unnecessary. A macro defined to "nothing" would be better approach (as answered below).

Answer (score 4):

```
static void foo_(int, int);

#ifdef NDEBUG
#define foo(x,y)
#else
#define foo(x,y)   foo_(x,y)
#endif
```

Comment: If he can change the function he might as well just put the conditional compilation in its implementation, and skip out on all the problem function-style macros introduce.

Comment: Yea i cant change the function or its name, just want it to basically skip the function call when not debugging. To optimize the code